# Hashmap with Intent not working

Tags: android, hashmap

I am trying to use HashMap to pass the values over to the other class but I am not sure why I got such weird results. I did a system.out.println and got [{Latitude=1.224119, username=borrow, Longitude=103.930041}],[{Latitude=1.224119, username=borrow, Longitude=103.930041}] repeatably but it shouldn't be the case as I have two different coordinates.

And when I pass it to the other class, it only returns me one coordinate and not two.

Anything went wrong with my code?

Get coordinates from db and pass to another class:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String, String> h1=new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (json != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Borrower_AP.this, json.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Longitude = c.getDouble("longitude");
                        Latitude = c.getDouble("latitude");
                        String s_lat = Latitude.toString();
                        String s_long = Longitude.toString();
                        h1.put("Latitude",s_lat);
                        h1.put("Longitude",s_long);
                        h1.put("username",username);
                        list.add(h1);
 Intent i = new Intent(this, BorrowerMap.class);
                i.putExtra("list", list);
                System.out.print(list);
                startActivity(i);
                        }
```

Get the values out:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    list=(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getExtras().get("list");
    String Latitude=list.get(0).get("Latitude");
    String Longitude=list.get(0).get("Longitude");
    String s_lat = Latitude.toString();
    String s_long = Longitude.toString();
    System.out.println(Latitude);
    System.out.println(Longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i follow your question than make the intent call after the loop body.Because it is getting only one list item and making the intent call in each loop process.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Longitude = c.getDouble("longitude");
                        Latitude = c.getDouble("latitude");
                        String s_lat = Latitude.toString();
                        String s_long = Longitude.toString();
                        h1.put("Latitude",s_lat);
                        h1.put("Longitude",s_long);
                        h1.put("username",username);
                        list.add(h1);
              }
 Intent i = new Intent(this, BorrowerMap.class);
                i.putExtra("list", list);
                System.out.print(list);
                startActivity(i);
```